# Cannot make sample xls file with Apache POI

Tags: java

I want to create a simple excel file to put some data in, but i have an error at Row and Cell line.
What is wrong?
   It says:

*1 .Row is an internal propery API and may be removed in future releases*

and

*2 .Cannot find symbol cell*

```
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
    //Create a new row in current sheet
 1. Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    //Create a new cell in current row
 2. Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    //Set value to new value
    cell.setCellValue("Blahblah");
```

I have include:

```
> import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet; import
> org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook; import
> org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell; import
> org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle; import
> org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat; import
> org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow; import
> org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet; import
> org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook; import
> org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor; import
> com.sun.rowset.internal.Row;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're having the wrong imports.

You should be using the following imports for Cell & Row.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
```

Use an IDE.